# Help with notation: $\triangle_{\gamma}\arg f$?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

What is denoted by the term $\triangle _{\gamma} \arg f$ , where $f$ is analytic in  region of complex plane and $\gamma$ is any curve in the region.
Can anyone explain me this notation with example?
Context it appeared in:
We take $f$ defined on $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that it is of the form $f=P+r$, where P is homogeneous poly. of degree k, and $r=o(|z|^k)$. Taking K to be the set given as $\{z:|P(z)|\leq c|z|^k\}$.
And we take c such that section of K by an arbitrary plane $z_2=constant$ is connected.
Then for any closed curve $\gamma$ in this section,  we have $\triangle _{\gamma} Arg f=2k\pi n$, where n is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having context (you should post context: it's helpful!), my best guess is that $\Delta_\gamma$ means the difference in value of a ***multivalued function*** at the beginning and endpoints of the curve.

For example, as $\arg x$ winds counterclockwise around the unit circle, if we pick the value $2 \pi n$ at the starting point, then it becomes $2 \pi (n+1)$ at the ending point, so the difference would just be $2 \pi$.

$\arg$ is nice, since we get the same difference no matter which branch we start at. Other multi-valued functions would depend on which branch you started at.

Comment: added context in the question

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$\triangle_\gamma\arg f:=\int\nolimits_\gamma d\arg f={\rm Im}\int_\gamma{f'(z)\over f(z)}\ dz\quad ?$$